# Query LDAP for all computer objects created in the last 24 hours

Tags: c#, filter, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to use an LDAP query to return all computer objects created in the last 24 hours.  My code currently looks like this:

```
//Declare new DirectoryEntry and DirectorySearcher
DirectoryEntry domainRoot = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://rootDSE");
string rootOfDomain = domainRoot.Properties["rootDomainNamingContext"].Value.ToString();
DirectorySearcher dsSearch = new DirectorySearcher(rootOfDomain);

//Set the properties of the DirectorySearcher
dsSearch.Filter = "(&(objectClass=Computer)(whenCreated>" + dateFilter.ToString() + "))";
dsSearch.PageSize = 2000;
dsSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName");
dsSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("whenCreated");
dsSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("description");
dsSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("operatingSystem");
dsSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("name");

//Execute the search
SearchResultCollection computersFound = dsSearch.FindAll();
```

This code does not return any objects, and I know for certain that there have been accounts created in the last 24 hours.
**EDIT:** I fixed this with the following code:

```
GetCompList(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)); //This sets the filter to one day previous

//Declare new DirectoryEntry and DirectorySearcher
DirectoryEntry domainRoot = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://rootDSE");
string rootOfDomain = domainRoot.Properties["rootDomainNamingContext"].Value.ToString();
DirectorySearcher dsSearch = new DirectorySearcher(rootOfDomain);

//Set the properties of the DirectorySearcher
dsSearch.Filter = "(&(objectClass=Computer)(whenCreated>=" + dateFilter.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss.sZ") + "))";
dsSearch.PageSize = 2000;
dsSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName");
dsSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("whenCreated");
dsSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("description");
dsSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("operatingSystem");
dsSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("name");


//Execute the search
SearchResultCollection computersFound = dsSearch.FindAll();
```

The secret is the line :

```
dsSearch.Filter = "(&(objectClass=Computer)(whenCreated>=" + dateFilter.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss.sZ") + "))";
```

Comment: Yes, what is your question?  What errors are you running into?  Albeit i did it using Java, but the ideas are the same.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C# -" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: I have fixed the question. Sorry the original was so bad, I was in a hurry and flustered from fighting this all day.

Comment: I've re-opened this question. Please post your solution (along with the explanation - that a specific format for the date is needed) as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: please take the portion you stated was your fix and post it as an answer; you will be able to mark it as an answer, making it easier for others to find that may be encountering the same headaches as you!

Comment: I can't answer my own question for another 6 hours. I will answer it tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the answer was in the formatting of the whenCreated filter.  According to [This blogpost](http://blog.scottlowe.org/2006/10/11/finding-recently-created-active-directory-accounts/), the filter for whenCreated must be formatted like "yyyyMMddHHmmss.sZ", where Z is the offset from UTC.  What I did was created a method called

```
private void GetCompList(DateTime dateFilter) //This overloaded version of GetCompList takes a parameter of type DateTime, and only returns computers that were built after dateFilter
    {
        try
        {
            //Convert the dateFilter to a format appropriate for an LDAP query
            int offset = -8;
            //string strDateFilter = convertToCrazyFormat(dateFilter, offset);

            //string strDateFilter = dateFilter.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss");

            //Declare new DirectoryEntry and DirectorySearcher
            DirectoryEntry domainRoot = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://rootDSE");
            string rootOfDomain = domainRoot.Properties["rootDomainNamingContext"].Value.ToString();
            DirectorySearcher dsSearch = new DirectorySearcher(rootOfDomain);

            //Set the properties of the DirectorySearcher
            dsSearch.Filter = "(&(objectClass=Computer)(whenCreated>=" + dateFilter.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss.s" + offset.ToString()) + "))";
            dsSearch.PageSize = 2000;
            dsSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName");
            dsSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("whenCreated");
            dsSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("description");
            dsSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("operatingSystem");
            dsSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("name");
```

I then call the method like this:

```
GetCompList(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1));//Pass in a negative value that represents the time period you want objects from, in this case the last day
```