# Find recently created Active Directory users in C#

Tags: c#, active-directory, principal, userprincipal

I use this PowerShell to get the information of the users created in the last 24 hours from Active Directory:

```
 $ous = 'OU=test,DC=test,DC=local' $When = ((Get-Date).AddDays(-1)).Date $ous | ForEach { Get-ADUser -Filter {whenCreated -ge $When} -Properties whenCreated,* -SearchBase $_ }";
```

How can get same result use C#? Thanks for any help.

Here my C# code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // LDAP string to define your OU
        string ou = "OU=test,DC=test,DC=local";

        // set up a "PrincipalContext" for that OU
        using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "test.local", ou))
        {
            // define the "query-by-example" user (or group, or computer) for your search
            UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);

            // set whatever attributes you want to limit your search for, e.g. Name, etc.
            qbeUser.Surname = "ilgezdi";

            // define a searcher for that context and that query-by-example 
            using (PrincipalSearcher searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser))
            {
                foreach (Principal p in searcher.FindAll())
                {
                    // Convert the "generic" Principal to a UserPrincipal
                    UserPrincipal user = p as UserPrincipal;

                    if (user != null)
                    {
                        console.Write(user);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can change `if (user != null)` to `if(p is UserPrincipal)`

Answer (score 0):

`UserPrincipal` doesn't expose the date the account was created, so you can't use `PrincipalSearcher` to search for users based on that date.

You will have to use `DirectorySearcher`, which `PrincipalSearcher` uses in the background anyway - it just gives you more control.

There is [a question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10391174/query-ldap-for-all-computer-objects-created-in-the-last-24-hours) which answers this for finding computers, but this is the code adapted to find users:

```
var domainRoot = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://rootDSE");
string rootOfDomain = domainRoot.Properties["rootDomainNamingContext"].Value.ToString();
var dsSearch = new DirectorySearcher(rootOfDomain);

//Set the properties of the DirectorySearcher
dsSearch.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(whenCreated>=" + dateFilter.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss.sZ") + "))";
dsSearch.PageSize = 2000;
dsSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName");
dsSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("whenCreated");
dsSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sAMAccountName");

//Execute the search
using (SearchResultCollection usersFound = dsSearch.FindAll()) {
    foreach (SearchResult user in usersFound) {
        Console.WriteLine(user.Properties["sAMAccountName"][0]);
    }
}
```